# Links not working on Twitter Bootstrap Modal (2.3.2)

Tags: html, hyperlink, twitter-bootstrap-2

This is a very puzzling issue, but all the links I have in the below modal do not work (clicking on the links, nothing happens).  The code is below:

```
<section class="signupArtistModal">
<div id="myModal" class="modal-styling modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-toggle="modal" style="display:none">

  <div class="modal-header">
    <span class="top-cross">
    <a href="#" id="close-modal" data-dismiss="modal1" aria-hidden="true"><i class="fa fa-times fa-2x" style="float:right;"></i></a>
    </span>
    <br>
    <article class="modalTopPart welcome-modal-top">
    <p>Congratulations!</p>
    </article>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="center">
    <div class="share-first-text">Share with your friends and make this show happen.</div>

    <ul>
    <li style="display:inline; margin-right:10px;"><a href="https://twitter.com" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x"></i></a></li>
    <li style="display:inline;"><a href="https://facebook.com" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x"></i></a></li>
    </ul>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
</section>
```

Any idea what may be going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior is strange why it won't open the link, I can even right click and choose to open in a new tab. The solution I came up with is to use JavaScript inline to force the event. Here's the code for twitter you can apply the same to the Facebook tag: Here the twitter link works in this updated [JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/DivineChef/rMdLZ/45/)

```
<li style="display:inline; margin-right:10px;"><a href='http://twitter.com' 
 onclick='window.open("http://twitter.com");return false;'><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x">  
</i></a></li>
```

Comment: I want it hidden on page load unless it satisfies a certain condition, that's why I have hide.  I have a js function that loads the modal if it satisfies the condition.  The modal loads fine.  I mean the links (the FB link and the twitter link) do nothing.

Comment: In 3.x it's hidden by default is that the same for 2.3.2?

Comment: I removed the "hide" thing but the original problem, which is that the links aren't working, is still there. The modal is loading fine, and is acting as it should.  Links within the modal, are not working.

Comment: That's odd it works for me at http://jsfiddle.net/DivineChef/rMdLZ/35/ using your code but bootstrap 3.x.  I would look at previous bootstrap documentation to find some tag such as html=true, this is the case for popovers not allowing HTML content until you add this tag.

Comment: Could you try it with 2.3.2?

Comment: If you set up a fiddle with 2.3.2 resources I can take a look.

Comment: Could you follow up?  Any idea?

Comment: I sent you an updated solution and a JS Fiddle above. Find it?

Comment: Unfortunately it still isn't working with the updated fiddle.

Comment: I'm looking at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DivineChef/rMdLZ/45/

That you shared above.  Neither the Twitter nor Facebook link is working in Google Chrome.

Comment: Get a Mac it works fine on Safari and Chrome. Another thing you could try is placing the link <a tags outside the li.

Comment: I am also using Mac with Mavericks at home and Mountain Lion at work and both work fine. Don't know what the deal is with you, I would get someone else to try and also try my suggestion by putting the <a> links outside of the <li>

Comment: Someone just voted me up so it must work for someone other than me!